# Can I edit Swype's user dictionary to remove typos?

Tags: swype

Swype has become populated with numerous words that don't exist due to typos.

As a result it frequently gets words wrong or pops up with its hidden word tip.

Is there a way of viewing all the user added words in its dictionary to selectively delete them?

*I'm not sure if this is os/handset specific so I haven't tagged it as such, but I'm on Froyo on a Galaxy S.*

Comment: If you are getting lots of typos it sounds like you are using it wrong.  The swype mode doesn't add words to the dictionary, you have to type them out.  So you should only need to type a particular word once and just be more careful at that stage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to directly edit the dictionary.

You can delete any user-added word by highlighting it and hitting the Swype key.

Comment: According to the Swype guys this sort of thing is in the pipeline but a way off. http://forum.swype.com/showthread.php?1233-quot-Hidden-Word-quot-Tip-Notification

Comment: Good to hear :)