# Where does swype store the user dictionary?

Tags: swype, dictionary, text-prediction

Does anyone know where Swype stores the user dictionary? I wasn't careful enough at the outset and now it prefers "Amanfa" to "Amanda" which is hugely annoying. I haven't been able to delete it. I'd really like to at least see if I can't bushwhack my way to a back door and look through the dictionary myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I edit Swype's user dictionary to remove typos?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3571/can-i-edit-swypes-user-dictionary-to-remove-typos)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far, it seems like this dictionary has eluded people all over. There are a few things that have worked for most people as far as getting swype under control.

1. To **delete** a single word, type it using Swype, highlight it (by clicking or double clicking the word), and press the **Swype key** (button with "info" icon)
2. To **add** a word, type it very carefully letter by letter and press the **Swype key** to save it to the dictionary
3. To **batch add** multiple words to the dictionary (this has been tested and worked), type the words you wish to add in a text document (either on your phone or on your computer and then view it on your phone). Highlight the block of text and push the **Swype key**. This should add every word in the block to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In latest Swype beta (version 1.0.3.5809), there's an option `Personal Dictionary` in Swype settings. It's an easy GUI way to manage Swype user dictionary.