# Swype keyboard dictionary migration

Tags: swype

How to migrate a swype keyboard dictionary to another device (a new one for instance)?
When I buy a new phablet I have to collect words over again.

Answer (score 2):

From Swype [documentation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/mobile/%40web-enus/documents/collateral/nc_028051.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjN6vOV4P3SAhXFS7wKHbJmBk8QFggjMAE&usg=AFQjCNEkEAiz4YAZTbX8Ab4I476DLEWTmQ&sig2=rvUc5GuJYFZVJ7-ACECAUA)

Backup and Sync Demo: Register all Devices with Swype Connect • Download the latest build of Swype from the Google Play store

> • Open messaging application and long press on the Swype key to open Swype Settings
>
> • Select “My Words”, then select “Register Now” to activate Backup and Sync
>
> •In messaging application input names of friends a few times and select “Add word to Dictionary”
>
> • Long press Swype key to open Swype Settings, select “My Words” and then select “Edit My Dictionary” and you can view your dictionary
>
> •Multi-Device Dictionary Sync •

If using a brand new device without Swype previously installed

> • Go to “Android Settings”, “Applications”, “Swype”, and select “Clear Data”
>
> • Open messaging application; walk through the Swype registration process with your device email
>
> • Once activation is complete, go into “Swype Settings,” select “My Words,” and then select “Edit My Dictionary” and you will see that your dictionary has been completely restored
>
> • Go through this process with all your Android devices if desired

Comment: That's odd. But I can't see backup and sync menu in my swype.

Comment: I just re installed Swype and can see *backup and sync menu* did you forget to register the device? If you don't register, you cannot see. I can see the complete dictionary synced from my previous device

Comment: See this https://i.stack.imgur.com/iac43.png

Comment: Were you able to register and check ?

Comment: Nope. I can't an option of device registering. I've got Note4. Probably Samsung has done something with it...

Comment: Quite possible. Sammy messes up things

Answer (score 2):

Since Swype is EOL and no longer supported by its owner, but thankfully still functional, I have found the backup/registration/restore process unreliable. I was able to migrate the app from one device to another fairly easily, but found that the personal dictionary ("word list") is not included in that. The best solution I have come up with is this:

- "Manually" capture the contents from the old host/source Swype personal dictionary as described here: [Bulk word import into Gboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228574/127255). The Universal Copy tool mentioned there now supports a 'scroll mode' that allows you to capture more than the ~20 entries that fit on the screen at a time from the old list, but its still slow going.
- Transfer the flat-text list to the new host. I used a Google Keep item to do this.
- Bulk import the flat-text list to the new Swype installation as described here: [Where does swype store the user dictionary?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/11451/127255). Caveat: the bulk import process only accepts about 35 entries at a time, so multiple import passes will have to be made, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

2022 Swype-user here. The easiest (albeit still manual) solution allows you to transfer ~20 words at a time:

1. On your old phone, open your personal dictionary list on Swype
2. On your new phone, take a photo of your list of words
3. Using Google Lens (i.e. smart scanner) highlight the text in the photo
4. Copy and paste the words into any messaging app draft
5. Highlight all of the pasted words
6. Press the Swype key
7. Swype will prompt you to "Add all to dictionary"
8. Repeat until you've scrolled through your personal dictionary

Not ideal, but it was mindlessly easy. Happy Swyping!