# Bulk word import into Gboard

Tags: gboard, dictionary

I moved from my Redmi to Mi Mix 2 now and used the Mi Mover app but unfortunately, the words in my used keyboard Gboard weren't restored. Neither does the internal synchronization work, it says something like "sync is not available for devices with G suite accounts or Android for work profile".

Couldn't yet find a working solution for this issue, so I'm thinking about re-adding all words but don't want to do this one by one. I have a wordlist as a text file that would cover at least 80% of my custom words. Any way of adding this at once to Gboard dictionary?

Apart from Gboard dictionary, there seems to be a common Central Android custom word dictionary. Is Gboard also considering words from there? In case it is, maybe there's some API/interface to this Central place so I could add those words at least there, so they could be used by Gboard (and also by other keyboard apps should I ever decide to switch).

I don't mind which way to go in case at least one of both could be achieved.

Comment: If you could get them out into a text file (maybe) it could be transferred to the device, and opened. Maybe then each of the words could be highlighted for inclusion? Saves the 50% of typing work, at least. If it requires typing, perhaps a great big copy/paste from the source into a clean document could induce the action?

Comment: I have them already in a text file, each word per line. But it's annoying to select and add them one by one, especially because gboard does sometimes only really add them after a few typings.

Comment: Why one-by-one? Can't you open the text document, or copy a big list of them into any text field? Even a Messenger text field should allow a copy, especially a few hundred words at time (I don't know the upper bound).

Comment: Select every word one by one for inclusion, wasn't that what you suggested in your first comment? Understood it like this. A simple copy of all the words will not include them in the dictionary unfortunately.

Comment: I was responding to the idea you were copy and pasting one at a time. The inclusion has to be singular, certainly.

Comment: I believe an import/export is possible, are you still looking for a solution to this question?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander I would love a solution, if you're able to share one. I've been looking for an ability to bulk import/export custom dictionaries such as this, and it'd be highly useful being able to do (without having to manually do it word by word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just managed to move my Swype dictionary to Gboard and would like to share my technique. Please bear in mind that I am not able to program, so this technique is aimed at novices like myself. I used Android 9 on a Samsung Note 8.

I know it looks like a long and complicated process, but that's just because I've broken it down into small steps: if you have less than a thousand personal words in your vocabulary the whole thing shouldn't take more than about half an hour. At the end of the process, I uninstalled the two apps which I had installed, but that of course is up to you.

1. Open Swype and go to Edit My Dictionary.
2. Install and open Universal Copy: I found it on the notification bar
3. Tap the top-right icon which is a dotted square surrounding a solid rectangle. This will select everything on the screen. Then press the Copy icon which is two overlapping rectangles
4. Because I have Word on Android, I opened a new Word document and pasted into it the words that Universal Copy had copied. (It would probably have been quicker to use ES File Explorer to create a plain-text .txt file, but I did not think of this until too late).
5. Press Enter after the last word pasted so the cursor will be on a new line
6. Go back to Edit My Dictionary and scroll up until the words you have already copied have disappeared at the top of the screen
7. Go back to Universal Copy, which means going back to the notification bar at the top of the screen, and repeat steps 3 to 6 however many times you need to copy all the words from your Swype dictionary. (I have more than 700)
8. Optionally, go through the Word or .txt document you have just created, cutting out all the repetitions of "Personal Dictionary" which Universal Copy has faithfully copied each time it saw it on the screen. Also, remove any unwanted words on that list.
9. If you created a .txt document, call it `wordlist.txt`. If you created a Word document, you will need to Save As `wordlist.txt`. I had to do this and the next step on the PC but  I'm sure it's possible to do it on the phone.
10. Whichever way you created this `wordlist.txt` file, move it to the root of the SD card
11. Install and open User Dictionary Manager to import this file into your Android Personal Dictionary.
12. The most difficult part for me was finding the path to the root of my SD card. In the end, I found it on a Google app called Files, by selecting the file and then tapping the Information icon on the drop-down menu. My path was `/storage/14B5–E887/wordlist.txt`. Obviously your SD card will not be called `14B5–E887`, and depending on your version of Android and your phone, you may have a different path altogether.
13. The most satisfying part was checking this had worked by going TG board, choosing Settings, Dictionary Personal Dictionary, English (UK) and seeing all your Swype words appear… For some reason in duplicate :-( but this does not seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

The closest workaround I got perhaps is installing some third-party application (like [User Dictionary Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paolinoalessandro.dictionaryplus&hl=en) by [Alessandro Paolino](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Alessandro%20Paolino)).

This application essentially, lets you personalize your personal dictionary with words you usually use. It learns words you’ve used on Social Networks, Messaging Apps etc. to text files.

Some of its feature include:

> - Backup/Restore your Personal Dictionary (Premium Feature). Premium Version will allow you to get Premium features and to import more
>     words than the Free version.

User Dictionary Plus also allows importing of words from Text File but this is a premium feature:

[image]

*Note from author: The App works correctly with keyboards that access to Android User Dictionary (for example: GBoard from Google).*

Comment: This program doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I updated Gboard to a test version and I noticed that there is now an import/export option when you press the three dots on the top right next to the plus button to add a word to the dictionary. This might have been there before as well. Unfortunately, you will have to import every language separately and the "all languages" separately as well.

The easiest way is to export from the app of your old device and then import the same zip file/s to your new device. However, if you want to go the hard way or if you don't have the old phone any more, you can also just see how the text file in the zip file is structured and use that structure, then zip the text file and you can import that as well.

Comment: This didn't work for me on xiaomi

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1 - Pay attention to the format

Format your `personal-dictionary.txt` file following the provided sample/template. Copy and paste if you need to. The only thing(s) you are changing is adding one tab after each category, or 4 spaces. But don't mix tabs with spaces and vice versa.

The format is as follows:

`word_shortcut    your_word`

Example of EXACTLY how the file format should look.

```
# Gboard Dictionary version:1
drug    Degarelix   en-US
ruski   Ruskinaya   en-US
den dendog1 en-US
motha    motha#@*$#    en-US
nigh    night   en-US
til tiller  en-US
```

Also, the file encoding MUST be ASCII text.

#### Step 2 - Compress your document

**Do not use any other zip format other than the universal basic `.zip` format.**

Gboard will not recognize any other archive type e.g. .7zip, .tar.gz, etc. Also, Gboard will not recognize *any* type of file format.

So, put your newly created and made-up word list in a blank folder. The only file that should be in that folder is the .txt file. Compress the folder. Name the folder and the file whatever you like. You can even use one of those made-up words you made up.

Tips: Do not compress the .txt file first and then compress the folder on top of that. Either just compress the file (a folder gets created automatically)

#### Step 3 - Import the file

Open Gboard > Personal dictionary > Import > find your .zip file > tap/click one time > Gboard will do the rest.

Comment: It's December 2023, and I found I didn't even need to *zip* the text file now!